# ShareCompat.IntentBuilder Google+ sharing in full screen?

Tags: android, google-plus, android-sharing

I'm using the following code to post in Google+:

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainActivity.this)
      .setText("This is a sample test"
      .setSubject("This is my subject")
      .setType("text/plain")
      .getIntent()
      .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

It works. But it shows in a dialog. I remembered it was showing in full screen yesterday. Can I show it in full screen? (Because if I show it in dialog, my background is blinking for some reasons.)

Can anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `PlusShare.Builder` instead. Your share intent will look something like:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
.setType("text/plain")
.setText("Your Text")
.setTitle("title")
.getIntent();
staryActivityForResult(shareIntent, requestCode);
```

Comment: What is the PlusShare and how to get it?

Comment: PlusShare is  a helper class for sharing content on Google+. You just need to add google-play-services-lib to your project

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be ok.

Comment: It shows dialog instead of full screen again if setType("image/*"). What should I do?

Comment: i guess my question will be what type of image do you want to share? Is it an image stored on the device or does it have a url (that is an image from an online service)

Comment: Are there any difference between these two types? Currently my image is online but I get it and save it in the cache. And in addStream() I'm using the local image.

Comment: Or is there a way to disable soft keyboard showing up in Google+ dialog ?